# Greater-Than operator using an Arithmetic Circuit

Tags: ds.algorithms, arithmetic-circuits, circuits

How can I transform the term $x>C$ (i.e. the term assumes the value $1$ if $x>C$ and assumes the value $0$ otherwise) to an arithmetic circuit that computes it?

Where $x$ is the input to the circuit and $C$ is a known constant.

Comment: You can’t. Arithmetic circuits only compute polynomials, and the set of positive elements is not the zero set of a polynomial in any ordered ring.

Comment: Can you explain with a bit more details please?

Comment: Which part of that is unclear to you?

Comment: "the set of positive elements is not the zero set of a polynomial in any ordered ring"

Comment: Well, if the ordered ring is an integral domain, then a nonconstant polynomial can only have finitely many zeros, whereas there are infinitely many positive elements. If it’s not a domain, the argument gets a bit more messy, but it still works out.

Comment: I'm talking about a finite field, does it change the answer?

Comment: What do you mean by $x>C$ then? A finite field can’t be ordered. Which ordered structure do you take $x$ and $C$ from, and how do you represent them by elements of the finite field?

Comment: Well, I thought that I can compare between elements in the finite field by just looking at them as elements with the same value which are in the infinite (ordered) field. In particular I thought of the field of integers modulo $N$.

Comment: Bush: I suggest you try to reformulate the question to actually express what you are thinking of.

Comment: You can use interpolation to write any function on a finite field as an arithmetic circuit. Do you have other requirements?